# Android GCM app force closes at the GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this) line in my android app with unknown error

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging, illegalstateexception, android-permissions

I'm trying to create push notification service to my android app using gcm. I have encountered the following error in my project in the lines below:

```
// Make sure the manifest permissions was properly set 
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
```

The app is force cloasing at this line. I will show the log in the logcat:

```
07-23 12:53:47.619: D/AndroidRuntime(15575): Shutting down VM
07-23 12:53:47.619: W/dalvikvm(15575): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4163fc20)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575): Process: com.tonyjoseph.kra, PID: 15575
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tonyjoseph.kra/com.tonyjoseph.kra.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receiver for package com.tonyjoseph.kra
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5177)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receiver for package com.tonyjoseph.kra
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:151)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at com.tonyjoseph.kra.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
07-23 12:53:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(15575):    ... 11 more
07-23 12:53:49.379: I/Process(15575): Sending signal. PID: 15575 SIG: 9
```

The above log is the activity log of my app in logcat. One strange thing which has happened to me is that, while I was running my app, another message also started showing at the logcat as another saved filter. It's name was like this in the logcat: **com.google.android.gms (Session Filter)**. I don't know whether it has anything related to my app. But I'm showing this, because it may be helpful to clear the error. I will show that log also:

```
 07-23 11:12:42.999: W/ContextImpl(13335): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService.onCreate:165 android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService:2592 
07-23 11:13:05.509: W/GA-SERVICE(13335): Thread[Thread-237,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
07-23 11:15:05.809: W/ActivityThread(13335): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
07-23 11:41:39.409: W/ContextImpl(13335): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService.onCreate:165 android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService:2592 
07-23 11:41:39.469: W/GA-SERVICE(13335): Thread[Thread-238,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
07-23 12:50:09.119: D/SystemBroadcastService(13335): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=
07-23 12:50:09.709: W/ContextImpl(13335): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.games.service.INTENT } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.a:101 com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.c:373 
07-23 12:50:09.759: W/ContextImpl(13335): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.appstate.service.INTENT } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.appstate.service.AppStateIntentService.a:58 com.google.android.gms.appstate.service.AppStateIntentService.a:104 
07-23 12:50:11.339: W/dalvikvm(13335): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/google/android/gms/icing/impl/NativeIndex;
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335): Error linking native code, bailing from initialization
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load AppDataSearch from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at com.google.android.gms.icing.impl.NativeIndex.<clinit>(SourceFile:497)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at cgf.a(SourceFile:158)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at cgv.a(SourceFile:524)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at chg.run(SourceFile:287)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335):     at cft.run(SourceFile:38)
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335): Internal init failed
07-23 12:50:11.489: E/Icing(13335): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED intent due to initialization failure.
07-23 12:50:12.099: I/PeopleDatabaseHelper(13335): cleanUpNonGplusAccounts done.
07-23 12:51:52.229: W/ContextImpl(13335): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService.onCreate:165 android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService:2592 
07-23 12:51:53.089: W/GA-SERVICE(13335): Thread[Thread-315,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
07-23 12:51:56.749: W/GA-SERVICE(13335): Thread[Thread-315,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
07-23 12:52:50.539: D/SystemBroadcastService(13335): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=
07-23 12:52:50.719: W/ContextImpl(13335): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.games.service.INTENT } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.a:101 com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.b:368 
07-23 12:52:51.069: E/Icing(13335): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent due to initialization failure.
07-23 12:53:48.669: W/GA-SERVICE(13335): Thread[Thread-315,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
```

I don't know whether the above log came because of any error in my app. That's why I posted this here. If it is not relevant to the topic, you can delete it or neglect it.I didn't find any solution to my error in google or anywhere else. That's why I have asked here for a little help.

Here is my MainActivity:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.tonyjoseph.kra;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Controller aController;

// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
public static String name;
public static String email,mobile;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();


    // Check if Internet present
    if (!aController.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        // Internet Connection is not present
        aController.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting name, email from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");  
    mobile=i.getStringExtra("mobile");

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest permissions was properly set 
    //The error is in this line as mentioned by the logcat.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    // Register custom Broadcast receiver to show messages on activity
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {

        // Register with GCM            
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);

    } else {

        // Device is already registered on GCM Server
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {

            // Skips registration.              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.

            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    aController.register(context, name, email, regId,mobile);

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };

            // execute AsyncTask
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }

}
// Create a broadcast receiver to get message and show on screen 
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

            // Display message on the screen
            //lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");         

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            aController.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    };

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Cancel AsyncTask
            if (mRegisterTask != null) {
                mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
            }
            try {
                // Unregister Broadcast Receiver
                unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

                //Clear internal resources.
                GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I have also given the following permission in my AndroidManifest xml file. It is given below:

```
 <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

For full clarification, I will show the AndroidManifest.xml file:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tonyjoseph.kra"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.Controller"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.FirstUse"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first_use" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
</application>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer to my problem. Actually I forgot to include the receiver( broadcast receiver) in androidmanifest. The code which I have added to my AndroidManifest is this:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.tonyjoseph.kra" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Adding this code solved my problem and I was able to register my device to the server...

Comment: Hi Tee, I have already added this code in my manifest but still I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before few months.

But in my case I was debugging my app on Emulator, that was the problem.

When I run the same on real device it works fine.

Because emulator doesn't have DeviceId to register for push notification.

Comment: This happens to me on both emulator as well as real device.

Comment: My real device was samsung galaxy ace.

Comment: When i did code for push, it worked on emulator as well. So i don't think it depends upon device. Just make sure, your device has installed Google Play service.